# Javascript objects return prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance, prototype

I am having trouble writing an object constructor in Javascript. When I call a function on one of my instantiated objects, it always returns the value of the instantiated object. The flow is like this:

```
blue = tool('blue');
blue.jDom();     // returns '[<div id="blue" class="tool">...</div>]'
red = tool('red');
red.jDom();     // returns '[<div id="red" class="tool">...</div>]'
blue.jDom();     // returns '[<div id="red" class="tool">...</div>]'
```

I believe this is due to the private variables I included in the prototype declaration. If I move the prototype declaration into the constructor, everything works fine, but this is simply masking the fact that it seems like my objects are affecting the properties of the prototype, rather than themselves, by creating a new prototype for each object. Here is my related code:

```
function beget(oPrototype) {
    function oFunc() {};
    oFunc.prototype = oPrototype;
    return new oFunc()
};    

var tool = (function (){
        var protoTool = function(){

            var oTool = {},
                that = this,
                _bVisible = true,
                _oParentPane = 'body',
                _aoComponents,
                _sName = 'tool',
                _sSelector = '#' + _sName,
                _jDomElement;



            // this is the private tab object, needs to be refactored
                            // descend from a single prototype  
            function _tab() {

                var oTab = {},
                    _sHtml = '<li><a href="' + _sSelector + '">' + _sName + '</a></li>',
                    _jDomElement = $(_sHtml);

                function jDom() {
                    return _jDomElement;
                }

                oTab.jDom = jDom;

                return beget(oTab);
            };

            // this builds the jDom element 
            function _jBuild() {
                var sHtml = '<div id="' + _sName + '" class="tool"></div>';
                _jDomElement = $(sHtml)
                return _jDomElement;
            };

            // this returns the jQuery dom object
            function jDom() {
                if (typeof _jDomElement === 'undefined') {
                    _jBuild();
                }
                return _jDomElement;
            };

            function configure (oO){
                if (typeof oO !== 'undefined') {
                    if (typeof oO === 'string') {
                        var name = oO;
                        oO = Object();
                        oO.sName = name;
                    } 


                    _bVisible = oO.bVisible || _bVisible,
                    _oParentPane = oO.oParentPane || _oParentPane,
                    _aoComponents = oO.aoComponents || _aoComponents,
                    _sName = oO.sName || _sName,
                    _sSelector = '#' + _sName,
                    _jDomElement = undefined;
                    _oTab = _tab();

                    _oTab.jDom()
                        .appendTo(jDom())
                        .draggable({
                        revert: 'invalid',
                        containment: '#main',
                        distance: 10,
                    });
                } 

            };

            oTool.tMove = tMove;
            oTool.bVisible = bVisible;
            oTool.uOption = uOption;
            oTool.jDom = jDom;
            oTool.configure = configure;    

            return oTool;   
        }();

        var tool = function (oO) {
            that = beget(protoTool);
            that.configure(oO);
            that.configure = undefined;
            return that;
        };

        return tool;
    })();
```

Comment: Why are you writing this complex code? What is so hard about a constructor that assigns fields and then assign methods outside to the prototype. It will *just work*.

Answer (score 0):

First : inside the inner tool var definition, by 'that = beget(protoTool);' you must mean 'var that = beget(protoTool);'

What's going on in your code ? :
The tool definition gets evaluated in order to give tool a value. During this evaluation, a closure is made around protool.
But this closure is made only once, during this evaluation : all later calls to protool (made by a call to 'that', which has protools as prototype), will change the values of this first and only closure.
That is why you see this behaviour : the latest seen object will gets all attention since it updated the closure's values.
The solution is to have the right closure mades within the 'tool' inner var function definition.

But if i may, i would suggest to altogether go to a classic javascript class definition(s), using afterwise the new operator, which is, i believe, much easier to code/understand/debug.

Another rq : beget === Object.create in the latest javascript specifications (1.8.6)